# gulp task for finding grammar mistakes in md file

Tags: javascript, gulp, context-free-grammar

Is there any gulp task available for finding grammar mistakes in md file?

for example below task will format my md file like that i need to find grammer errors:

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const format = require('gulp-format-md');

gulp.task('format', () => {
  return gulp.src('README.md')
    .pipe(format())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just now i got an idea how to achieve my requirement, please refere blow links:

https://rollout.io/blog/improve-documentation-by-automating-spelling-and-grammar-checks/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/write-good